# Como hago este div con position: absolute; responsive? Html Css Angular

Tags: html, css

Tengo 2 **componentes** diferentes en **Angular**, un componente llamado **banner** y un componente llamado **about** que contiene un div en donde va a ir una foto. El **div** de la foto debe achicarse y subir exactamente como lo hace el **div** del banner, coincidiendo con la **franja blanca** mostrada en la foto. Busque de varias formas, con **vw** o asignándole porcentajes al **width** y al **top** y no lo puedo solucionar.

**Acá está el código del banner:**

-Html

```
<div class="bannerContenedor">
  <img src="./assets/banner.jpg" alt="baner">
</div>
```

-Css

```
.bannerContenedor{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.banner{
  border: 4px #ffffff  solid;
  height: 45.6vw;
  width: 78.9vw;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

**Acá está el código del about:**

-Html

```
<div class="aboutContenedor">
  <div class="divPrincipal">
    <div class="divSecundario">
      <img class="imagen" src="../assets/imgs/Foto.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-Css

```
.aboutContenedor{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #297ea6;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 4px #ffffff  solid;
}
.divPrincipal{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 854px;

}
.divSecundario{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 13%;
  width: 13vw;
  height: 13vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: var(--DegradesNegroBlanco);

}
.imagen{
  position: absolute;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 11vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

[image: Imagen del about]

[image: Div 2]

[image: Div 3]